# Error while building Net Application in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

The following few lines of my code are giving errors :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <mmsystem.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

int main()
{...
```

The code is suppose to work using Windows SDK so I added property pages accordingly

But while building in Visual Studio 2012 gives following errors :

```
 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory   4

3   IntelliSense: name must be a namespace name 11
4   IntelliSense: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name 140
5   IntelliSense: expression must have class type   140
6   IntelliSense: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name 141
9   IntelliSense: identifier "S" is undefined       145
```

Answer (score 0):

keep your stdfx.h outside your projects folder

Comment: I haven't kept it anywhere. I have just included the directiories C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include and C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\gl in the property sheet

Comment: do one thing,  remove existing stdfx.h file from your project then create one sample project and copy same file from that project put in your project

Comment: there is no stdfx.h file in my project. just the above code in a file in the project